# How to order by conditions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting

It's difficult to express ... because it's not ORDER BY or ORDER BY FIELD what I'm looking for.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE '%xxx%' 
OR category_name LIKE '%xxx%' 
OR description LIKE '%xxx%';
```

What I need is to sort results based in:
 - first, the ones that matches the like with "name" field
 - secondly, the category_name
 - last, the description

So I have results sorted and first the results where "xxx" was found in name.

As I told this is not ORDER BY , since that sort results based in the VALUE, not in the field matches.

Comment: Please post your expected results and table structure of data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case` in `order by` to sort results according to your criteria like

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  TABLE 
WHERE (
    `name` LIKE '%xxx%' 
    OR category_name LIKE '%xxx%' 
    OR description LIKE '%xxx%'
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN `name` LIKE '%xxx%' 
    THEN 0 
    WHEN category_name LIKE '%xxx%' 
    THEN 1 
    WHEN description LIKE '%xxx%' 
    THEN 2 
    ELSE 3 
  END ASC
```

Comment: perfect anstwer